# matlab contourf with gradual change of color

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

folks,

I have an image matrix and created the following figure using

```
contourf(my_matrix)
colorbar
```

[image]

Is it possible to make the color change gradually between the contour lines, instead of filling these spaces with solid color?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I want to add just few more words. Be careful about applying techniques like 'shading interp' because, as you probably know, interpolating means adding new points, creating new data. If we observe the figure you posted, we understand that you are plotting a field with "only" ten different values. I suggest you to use always commands like 'imagesc' that plot original values unless your priority is the figure aesthetic more than the underlying data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cinico's solution didn't work for me. Here's what I used:

```
% Set Data
data = (1:100)'*(1:100);

figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
% Binned Color
contourf(data);
subplot(1,2,2)
% Gradual Color
pcolor(data);
hold on;
shading interp; 
contour(data,'LineColor','k')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try `shading interp` command after the plot is done

but...

the most probable thing is that your data is not "gradual". What I mean is: either you have value 2 or 4 or 10 etc, not 2.2 or 4.6 or 10.1 etc.

So, you could not have the intermediate colours because that would mean that you would have intermediate values (which you don't).

Comment: Jucestain is right.

I didn't noticed that you were using contourf. This type of plot doesn't let interpolate the colours.

You can in fact use `shading interp`, as I suggested, if you make a `pcolor` plot.